# How to download a canvas rendered pdf file opening in pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, java, html, pdf.js

I have zero knowledge with regard to coding. I desperately need to download a pdf file which is being shown in the fashion attached to this post. The download button is not working and I've tried everything which I can to download the file. Any help is welcome. Things which I've tried are

> Finding file source in network tab under inspect element
>
> Finding any URl leading to the pdf again in the inspect elements tab.
>
> Saving the page as Html, upon which it downloads but never opens again with the pdf required.

Also in my limited research which I could make sense of was, the page used canvas element to render the pdf. Text of pdf is seen to be entered manually in a separate layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address of the pdf being rendered is actually visible in the url on your image.

the `../../` means go up 2 directories.

So that means the absolute url for your pdf is this.

https://www.time4education.com/MoodlePages/catmttt/cat20materialvideos/VAHO1002103.pdf